# Is advice for standardized test allow in the context of writing english?

Tags: discussion

To give a concrete example, I was preparing for the writing task for the GRE which has an issue and argument essay. I was confused about the difference and other details about the instructions and wanted to get a concrete answer on what the difference is. Is this the right site to ask this or where may I ask something along these lines

Note I am looking a right answer about the writing advice. There might multiple but I'd care for any one single answer. Maybe the simplest one I would request on this hypothetical question.

Comment: This seems more like a question about the GRE than about English. You may get better answers on study sites for the GRE or the [GRE site itself](https://www.ets.org/gre/revised_general/prepare/analytical_writing)

Comment: [ell.se] might also be a good place to ask, since the question would be about learning and being tested on one's English language skills.

Comment: @ColleenV thanks collen. I've been through that and the GRE books I bought and still need a way to answer my question more directly.

Comment: Not every question about something written in English is a question about learning English. ELL can help with specific questions about English. If your question fits with what is [on-topic](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on ELL, we will be happy to have it. Historically, questions asking for a fluent speaker to explain a block of text/guess at what it actually means haven't been well received. The [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/) post on ELL's meta has some advice for writing questions that is worth looking over.

Comment: @ColleenV what about something like this: https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/31465/does-defending-one-position-strongly-a-way-to-get-a-high-mark-for-a-gre-issue-re?noredirect=1#comment47252_31465

does it belong to any site?

Comment: @ColleenV on the links you've provided for GRE, where do u ask questions for those sites?

Comment: I don't know of any specifically, but a quick search for "GRE test help forum" turned up this link that looks promising: http://greprepclub.com/forum/